# Using paginate_links() to generate “01, 02, 03, 04” paginations

Tags: pagination

I have this code

```
$format = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link,
            'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
        $format .= $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( 'page/%#%',
            'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

        /*Set up paginated links.*/
        $links = paginate_links( array(
            'base'      => $pagenum_link,
            'format'    => $format,
            'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'current'   => $paged,
            'mid_size'  => 1,
            'after_page_number' => '.',
            'add_args'  => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
            'prev_text' => '',
            'next_text' => '',
            'type'      => 'list'
        ) );
```

It works ok but it generates pagination like "1, 2, 3, 4...Last Number"

Can this be achieved using paginate_links() function to generate paginations like this "01, 02, 03...19, 20 Last Number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you need to take two main steps:

**Step 1:** Instead of `1, 2, 3, 4...Last Number` you need `1, 2, 3...19, 20, Last Number`

**Step 2:** You need to add `0` prefix in the pagination numbering when the number is less than `10`, that is: `01, 02, 03...19, 20, Last Number`

This is definitely possible using [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) function.

## Solution for Step 1:

To make sure 3 pagination numbers show up from the two ends, you need to use the attribute: `'end_size' => 3`

## Solution for Step 2:

To make sure numbers less than `10` are prefixed with `0`, you need to use the filter hook: [`number_format_i18n`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/number_format_i18n/)

## Final CODE:

First, place the following function somewhere in your `functions.php` file:

```
    /* Filter function to be used with number_format_i18n filter hook */
    if( ! function_exists( 'wpse255124_zero_prefix' ) ) :
    function wpse255124_zero_prefix( $format ) {
        $number = intval( $format );
        if( intval( $number / 10 ) > 0 ) {
            return $format;
        }
        return '0' . $format;
    }
    endif;
```

Then, use the following CODE instead of the one you've provided in your question:

```
    $format = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link,
            'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
    $format .= $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks() ? user_trailingslashit( 'page/%#%',
        'paged' ) : '?paged=%#%';

    add_filter( 'number_format_i18n', 'wpse255124_zero_prefix' );

    /*Set up paginated links.*/
    $links = paginate_links( array(
        'base'      => $pagenum_link,
        'format'    => $format,
        'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current'   => $paged,
        'mid_size'  => 1,
        'end_size'  => 3,
        'after_page_number' => '.',
        'add_args'  => array_map( 'urlencode', $query_args ),
        'prev_text' => '',
        'next_text' => '',
        'type'      => 'list'
    ) );

    remove_filter( 'number_format_i18n', 'wpse255124_zero_prefix' );
```

Now you should get your expected pagination.

Comment: Yes, step 2.
It works perfect for me! Thank you.